# Show link next to "Size" chart in Single WooCommerce Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have one weird problem that i cant fix myself. I use this function to show link next to  Size text https://www.yeswedress.fr/produit/jovani-robe-cocktail-trapeze/

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 
'bbloomer_custom_action', 5 
 );

function bbloomer_custom_action() {
echo '<a href="' . get_site_url() . '/guide-des-tailles/" target="_blank" 
class="link5">Guide des tailles</a>';

}

.link5 {
float:left;
margin-top:-70px;
margin-left:80px;
}
```

Actually link is showing at bottom of product description, and i want to show next to "Taille :" section, and i want to show like in image bellow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3WSz.png

Any help?

Comment: Try to add it with pure css: 

Tailie:after {

}

Comment: Instead of showing this code, show the final HTML, and tag your question with appropriate tags. Just because you're using Wordpress, does not make this question _about_ Wordpress. Try [tag:css] instead.

Comment: Will try to post.